# upgrading rails app from 1.8.7 to ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails application running rails 3.0.20 and ruby 1.8.7
i want to upgrade to 1.9.3.
the stages i toke in order to start the process are so:

```
rvm user ruby-1.9.3
rvm gemset create upgradegems
rvm use ruby-1.9.3@upgradegems
```

now... i ran bundle. and i have a conflict with the twitter gem and the omniauth gem
so i updated them both.
then ran bundle again and it succeeded

now what?..
i tried running

```
rails s
```

and i got this error:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194@amazonto/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing_from_s3_library': uninitialized constant Gattica::Auth::VERSION (NameError)
```

what am i doing wrong? and how do i fix? 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not really your code, but its the library you are using Gattica, it wasn't updated for three years, try to put this on your Gemfile

```
gem "gattica", :git => "https://github.com/chrisle/gattica.git"
```

That's a fork that works great with ruby 1.9.x